# Approximation theory in Lp spaces (Reference Needed)

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces, approximation-theory

I am looking for some reference on approximation theory in Lp spaces.

I have found a number of papers like: [paper1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021904587901171) , [paper2](http://inmabb-conicet.gob.ar/publicaciones/actas-del-congreso-monteiro/12/10-cuenya.pdf) etc.

I was wondering if there is a book or a monograph that will contain summary of know results.
Thank you very much.